# Evaluating functions in different coordinate systems

Tags: differential-geometry

I was wondering if there exists a well defined tool in differential geometry which can evaluate an object, such as a function, in a different, but given, coordinate system that could describe even a different manifold. What I have in mind is a sort of generalization of the Dirac delta.

For example:
I have a function $f(x)$ let's say with $\{x\}$ pointing the natural coordinates of the Minkowski manifold. Then, applying this tool, let's call it $R(x \rightarrow X)$, I have the function evaluated now on $\{X\}$, which are for example the Krusckal coordinates for the Schwarzschild manifold: $R(x\rightarrow X) f(x) = f(X)$.

If the answer is yes, it exists, I would like to know more about it. If the answer is no, as I suspect, I would like to understand why an object like that cannot be defined.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what $f$ and $\{x\}$ are. Let me be more clear, with an example, where

- $f$ is a tensor field (scalar, vector or tensor function of any order) representing a physical quantity in an abstract notation, i.e.  representing a physical quantity as a function of space $\mathbf{r}$, it's an absolute quantity independent on the coordinates you use to describe the space (if we're in Classical Mechanics, the spacetime if we're in Relativistic Mechanics), $f(\mathbf{r})$
- ${x_i}$, ${X_k}$ are two sets of coordinates you use to describe the space, either $\mathbf{r}(x_i)$ or $\mathbf{r}(X_k)$, so that you can write the function $f(\mathbf{r})$ as a function of the coordinates

  $f^x({x_i}) = f(\mathbf{r}(x_i)) \qquad , \qquad$
  $f^X({X_k}) = f(\mathbf{r}(X_k))$,

  where the indices of the function $f$ remember us the independent variables we're using to describe the absolute function of space $\mathbf{r}$.

In this case, what makes you go from a description using coordinates $\{ x_i \}$ to the one using coordinates $\{ X_k \}$, or viceversa, is the law of change of coordinates between them, i.e. $x_i(X_k)$ or the inverse relation (**assuming that it's invertible**) $X_k(x_i)$,

$f^x({x_i}) = f^x({x_i}(X_k)) = f^x \circ x_i(X_k) = f^X(X_k)$,

i.e. you apply the composition of the function $f^x$ and the rule for change of coordinates to get $f^X$, that you can interpret as the tool you're looking for.

If $f$ is not a tensor field, but is rather a component of a tensor field in a given basis, or a vector of a base itself, it's likely that also the matrix of change of basis appears in the transformation.

Comment: Ok, let me better explain the context. I'm dealing with a model that assumes gravity as a quantum field over Minkowski spacetime. I need to build an interaction such that it contains an appropriate operator which, acting on the state of gravity (or rather being braketed between two of them), has as outcome something, what I have called R, that changes the coordinates of the other quantities in my calculation. In this sense I was thinking about a "generalized" Dirac delta, because in the same line of the calculation this object could "enforce" the new coordinates, even for different manifolds.

Comment: Your application is far beyond my knowledge of the topic. I guess the best thing to do, is to  ask another question about the specific topic with suitable tags

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely certain I understand the question. If a function $f$ is defined on a manifold $M$ (so for example, $f:M\rightarrow \mathbb R$) then there's no canonical tool to evaluate it on some different manifold $N$ - indeed what would that even mean?  Given any function $\phi:N\rightarrow M$ we could define $f_N:= f\circ \phi$ which is a function $N\rightarrow \mathbb R$ but you'd have to provide that $\phi$ yourself.

For example, let's say you have some coordinate chart $(U,x)$ on $M$ and another coordinate chart $(V,y)$ on $N$. You say that you have a function $T_{y\rightarrow x}:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ which eats the $y$-coordinates of a point $p\in V$ and spits out the $x$-coordinates of a point $q\in U$, in such a way that $T_{y\rightarrow x}$ is a homeomorphism.  This would define such a $\phi$ via
$$\phi : V\ni p \mapsto x^{-1}\big(T_{y\rightarrow x}\big[y(p)\big]\big)$$

It sounds like that's what you have in mind. Operationally, you're just plugging four different numbers into a function from $\mathbb R^4\rightarrow \mathbb R$. It's not clear to me what significance you would expect this to have, but as long as you have a pointwise map from $N\rightarrow M$ then you could define such a thing.